# can't solve problem with updating old array data

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm having a problem with updating **redux** `array`. I'm trying to increase quantity of existing data but my code is updating the whole old data with new one.

Here's my code:

```js
addToTakenOrder(state) {
    const newOrder = state.itemStore;

    // takenOrder is initialState and itemStore too, they are both array and quantity is number
    const existingOrder = state.takenOrder.find((item) => item.id === newOrder.id);

    // quantity is part of itemStore
    if (existingOrder) {
        existingOrder.quantity += newOrder.quantity;
        state.totalOrderPrice += state.totalPrice;
    } else {
        state.takenOrder = newOrder;
        state.totalOrderPrice += state.totalPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debug & console log the state and existingOrder itself on runtime? Which state variable did the problem persists? The takenOrder??

Comment: @DhanaD. yeah i did console log and it's saying existingOrder is undefined

Comment: So, the `find` didn't find anything. Either newOrder.id is not inside `takenOrder` or you are comparing a string with an int which won't match since you are using `===`

Comment: From what I see of your code you are just mutating `state`, whatever that is. What is this `addToTakenOrder` function? Is it a reducer function? A random function that `state` is passed to? Please [edit] to clarify what you want this code to do and include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.

Comment: Hello @DilAk, I hope you have found the provided response helpful. If it sufficiently answers your question, would you kindly consider marking it as the accepted answer? If you need more details or have further inquiries, I would be more than happy to provide additional information. Your feedback is highly valued. If you're still seeking assistance or have any more questions, please do not hesitate to ask

Answer (score 1):

the way you're updating the `state.takenOrder` array is the issue for Redux reducer. When you find an existing order, you're correctly updating its quantity, but you're not updating the `state.takenOrder` array itself. Another thing to consider is `else` block, where you're replacing the entire `state.takenOrder` array with `newOrder`, which is not correct *if you want to add `newOrder` to the array*.

Here's a revised version of your code that should work:

```js
function addToTakenOrder(state) {
  const newOrder = state.itemStore;

  const orderIndex = state.takenOrder.findIndex((item) => item.id === newOrder.id);

  let newTakenOrders = [];

  if (orderIndex !== -1) {
    // Create a new array with updated quantity for the existing order
    newTakenOrders = state.takenOrder.map((item, index) => 
      index === orderIndex ? { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + newOrder.quantity } : item
    );
  } else {
    // Add the new order to a new array created from the existing takenOrder array
    newTakenOrders = [...state.takenOrder, { ...newOrder }];
  }

  return {
    ...state,
    takenOrder: newTakenOrders,
    totalOrderPrice: state.totalOrderPrice + state.totalPrice
  };
}
```

Changes made:

- `findIndex` is used to get the index of the existing order. This allows you to modify the item directly in the `state.takenOrder` array.
- Used `map` to create a new array for the case where the order exists. This ensures that the original `state.takenOrder` array is not mutated.
- In the case where the order does not exist, the spread operator is used to *create a new array* with the *existing orders* and the *new order* added.
- Returned a new state object with updated `takenOrder` and `totalOrderPrice`, ensuring that the original state is not mutated.

This approach should correctly update your state in Redux.

Comment: If you are assuming this is a reducer function, then it still has the issue with mutating the `state` reference. I think you may be on the right track though.

Comment: I think this should avoid mutation of the state, right? https://hastebin.com/share/yogomewore.javascript

Comment: Yes, the code in that link appears to apply the immutable update pattern correctly. We still don't know what this function is for or where it's called. It's certainly mutating the passed `state` argument, but if the OP is using Redux-Toolkit, then writing mutable state updates is not only allowed (*works by mutating a draft copy of the state using immer.js under the hood*) but it's also preferred since it allows you to write more succinct code. We need more context from the OP though.